# "in" versus "to" in "He went running {in / to} the park."

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs, ellipsis

Do you agree that:

> 1. He went running to the park.
> 2. He went to the park running.

mean the same thing - "He got to the park by running."

Now, if I want to say: **He went to the park to have a run.** I need to say

> 3. He went running in the park.

But I am confused about "He went running in the park". Native speakers say it means "He went to the park to have a run."

But **in** means **inside** not **in the direction of**, hence, (3) should mean "He started to run in the park" and not "he went to the park to have a run". Or maybe (3) has two meanings?

"to the park" = in the direction of the park
"in the park" = inside the park

So, how come **(3) He went running in the park** can mean "He went to the park to have a run"?

Comment: It seems like you understand "to have a run" well enough. If that's the case, you probably can understand this "go something-ing" as "go (out) for that something" (e.g. "He went running" ~ "He went for a run"). I think this "go something-ing" is most common with those verbs that involve moving, sports, or outdoor activities, which, usually sound like fun. :-)

Comment: I think about "He went running in the park" as "*He performed the act of running inside the boundaries of the park*".  Your sentence (3) doesn't really **mean** "he went to the park to have a run" it only implies it because in order to run **in** the park you first have to go **to** the park. Semantically they both come to the same result but they aren't really equivalent.  Consider the case where he went to the park for the purpose of running, but when he got there the trail was flooded. Here you can see that going to the park to run is not the same as going running in the park.

Comment: @Jim, seems like you are the only person who understood the crux of my question. I wish you would have posted your answer as a real answer not a comment.

Comment: @Jim I guess that (3) doesn't really mean "he went to the park to have a run" but it's more like "he went for a run in the park".

Comment: Running in the park is fun. You see? It is an activity and a gerund noun. [Also: please note that we say: "I wish you had posted your answer as a real answer not a comment.."  So, you can see this is not *in* versus *to* by that transformation.

Comment: "I wish you wouldn't have posted" means that he was reluctant to do so.

Comment: @Lambie Running in the park. - is a gerund. He went running - is a participle.

Comment: @user1425 Running in the park is fun. Running = gerund **noun**. And the correct English is: **I wish you hadn't posted** . and **not**: wouldn't have posted. It's best to check before correcting a native speaker....

Comment: He went running, riding, camping etc. are gerund nouns and refer to **activity**. Camping, running, riding are fun. There is no participle. You ask native speakers and then ignore what they say or try to contradict them. Well, here, you are mistaken....

Comment: "I wish you would stop lecturing me" is a perfectly correct sentence, don't you think? This usage is not widespread but it's not wrong. Different natives say different things. I contradict only those who can't prove to be correct on the matter. It's a debate after all. "Running in the park is fun." is not a legit example. Different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

- He went running in the park. [The activity he performed]
- **Running in the park** is fun. [Gerund noun]
- He went to the park running.

is like:

- He went to the park walking. [on foot].

The sentences are not the same. The second explains his means of locomotion.

- He went running to the park.
- He went walking to the park.

Those two are the same as the previous two and different from the first two.

However, there is no in the park/ to the park opposition.

to indicates an endpoint here. whereas: in the park is like at school, in the building etc. it is a prepositional phrase. Not a phrasal verb.

Answer (score -1):

First, you should cut down on the unnecessary stuff to get down to the exact problem you're having here, if you want to figure this out more easily.

For instance, "He went running in the park." can be cut down to "He went running." (all prepositional phrases are unnecessary, and can be removed for a grammatically correct sentence by definition). "To" is often used as an infinitive with a verb, but "to the park" is a prepositional phrase, so the other sentence can be reduced to "He went to have a run." The other "to have" phrase is indeed an infinitive.

There isn't any difference in the meaning of these two sentences. The second one sounds like passive voice, although it technically isn't, as far as I'm aware. They functionally mean the same thing, but the second one ("to have a run") isn't as common. It may be more common in British English, where "have a(n) (verb used as noun)" is more colloquial, but I'm rather talking out of my rear end at this point.

I can't really explain "why" to you. That would be like asking "Why does the word 'apple' refer to a sweet, red fruit?" It would be a question of the origin of grammar rather than plain etymology, though.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

> “He went running in the park”

Means he went to the park in order to exercise by running.

One could say also

> “He went running at the park,”

which means the same thing.

If we break the sentence down,

> “He went running,”  - tells us what he did;
>
> “in the park,” - tells us where he did it.